# Python print ">>" stream modifier - porting to python3

Tags: python

I'm porting the HJB package from Python2 to 3.

It's using the output-stream option of `print` - what's the most appropriate way to port this to Python3?

```
def write_message(message, to=sys.__stdout__):
    def handle_message():
        print >> to, "*" * 60
        print >> to, message
        print >> to, "*" * 60
    return handle_message
```

Something like this:

```
def write_message(message, to=sys.__stdout__):
    def handle_message():
        star_line = "*" * 60
        if ( sys.version_info < ( 3, 0 ) ):
            print >> to, star_line
            print >> to, message
            print >> to, star_line
        else:
            print( star_line, file=to )
            print( message,   file=to )
            print( star_line, file=to )
        return handle_message
```

Is it that simple?
I've been coding python for more years than I care to remember, but never come across this "operator" before.

**EDIT: Final Version**

```
from __future__ import print_function

...

def write_message(message, to=sys.__stdout__):
    def handle_message():
        star_line = "*" * 60
        print( star_line, file=to )
        print( message,   file=to )
        print( star_line, file=to )
    return handle_message
```

Comment: The `file` keyword argument is correct. Unless you need to support truly ancient versions of Python (2.5 or earlier),  though, just import the `print` function and stick with that.  `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: Also note: If it doesn't need to continue to run on Python 2, just use the `2to3` converter to perform the conversion (with `-f print` it will only perform the one fixer). If it needs to run on Python 2 as well, just run the fixer, *then* add the `from __future__ import print_function` import to the top of the module. More foolproof than manually changing each point of use.

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost positive that code won't run in Python 3 - it'll give a syntax error.

Instead, if the minimum version of Python your library supports is >= [2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html), then add `from __future__ import print_function` to the top of your file and just use the Python3 `file=` argument you're already using.

Comment: @HeapOverflow - Yeah you're right, my apologies.  I'll delete my comment.  I was lead astray by Py3 syntax errors on other Py2 prints ending in commas.  I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @Kingsley Hmm, an ending comma shouldn't make it a syntax error, either. For example, `print >> to, message,` should successfully result in the tuple `(0, 1)` after setting `print = to = message = 1`.